# 6-speed automatic transmission w/ OD lock-up torque converter Fluid requirements?

Tags: hyundai, atf

Does a 6-speed automatic transmission w/OD lock-up torque converter require Transmission fluid?  The vehicle is a 2012 Hyundai Accent.

Comment: An automatic transmission does need fluid. Not sure what you mean by a sealed unit?

Comment: Even in BMW 5 series I've seen sealed AT systems.

Comment: "An automatic transmission does need fluid" they have since they were invented.

Answer (score 2):

The CVT transmission available as an option on the Hyundai Accent is (supposedly) sealed for life. The 6-speed automatic transmission is not sealed for life, and is inspected on a 'service 3' schedule (24,000, 72,000, 120,000, 168,000 miles, etc). There is no schedule for replacing the fluid, unless one of those inspections finds an issue.

If you have a problem with the transmission on that particular vehicle, be aware that the power train is covered by a 10year/100,000 miles warranty - so let the dealer sort any issues out rather than doing it yourself.